# Python does not recognize two strings as equal

Tags: python

I'm a total newbie learning Python and I'm making a small text-based Fallout clone. However, I'm having issues with one set of code:

```
def PCgender():
    gender = input("Is your character male or female? \n")
    gender = gender.lower()
    gender = str(gender)
    if gender=="male":
        print("Atta, cowboy! ")
    elif gender=="female":
        print("You go, girl! ")
    else:
        #Triple quotes here because there's both single and double quotes in this sentence and to make it go over multiple lines. 
        print("""Aw, you special snowflake, you! But I'm fraid I haven't coded for anything 
        except "male" and "female", so please try one of those! """)
        PCgender()
PCgender()
```

Even when the input is male or female, it still returns the else function. I have a very similar block further up which works perfectly, but this doesn't and I have no idea why.

Update: I tried commenting out all of this code, but VS still ran it, so I restarted the program. Same problem. I made a new file, copied it over. Still ran the code as if it wasn't commented out. As per some nice people's suggestions, I tried running print(repr(gender) and it returned 'male'. Strange.

I then decided to remove the .lower() function and it worked! When I re-added it, it kept working, so IDK what I did wrong. The original code is up there, so please tell me what I did wrong, if you know!

Cheers!

Comment: `gender = gender.lower` is missing parentheses, and therefore assigns *the method itself* to the name, rather than the return value. Had you tried e.g. `print(repr(gender))` as part of your debugging, you would have noticed this.

Comment: Using recursion to repeat a request for user input can cause your program to eventually crash. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses missing:

```
gender = gender.lower()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it; same result, still. I was actually typing "male" and "female"  with lower case, so it shouldn't have been an issue regardless.

Comment: print out the gender variable and see what you have got

Comment: @804R No you weren't. You were comparing the string representation of the function `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x0050F040>` to a string `'male'`

Comment: @CoryKramer He has corrected it.

Comment: @hsfzxjy, Tried that, too, before posting here. The string appears, as far as I can tell, to be exactly the same.

Comment: @804R Delete the first 3 lines and use `gender = input("Is your character male or female? \n").lower()`

Comment: any spaces or other invisible characters?

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for the tip, but still nothing. The output is the same (so thanks for helping me make it shorter!), but it's still not recognized.

Comment: @hsfzxjy Nope, I've tried rewriting everything several times.

Comment: Amazing, I will try it out.

Comment: @hsfzxjy Thank you! I tried redoing again, for good measure, so now every character is verified, but still nothing. :/

Comment: @804R I've copied your code directly into my editor, run it with python3, and I got "Atta cowboy!" when I typed male.

Comment: Show me more details, like python version, operating system as well as character set.

Comment: @hsfzxjy Yeah, I just tried commenting out everything and it still ran the code! Restarted visual studio, still got the same result! WTH? Python shouldn't  even be able to see the code it now spouts  at me!

Comment: @hsfzxjy I believe I have the very latest Python version (3.5.#?); where can  I check that? I'm running Visual Studio on a W8.1 machine. Where do  I find the character set?

Comment: If you are using English version of windows , the character set will ve ascii

Comment: so are you using cmd to debug or others like console in visual studio(if there is)?

Comment: what about print(repr(gender))?

Comment: @hsfzxjy VS has a built-in debugger, but there's no error code. It goes to the "else" option and back again.

Comment: print(repr(gender)), whats the result?

Comment: @hsfzxjy It says 'male' in single quotes. But I removed the .lower function and now it's working for some reason. Thank you! :D

Comment: amazing... update your previous version to the question, I wanna find out why..

Comment: and also, accept the answer if your problem has been settled :)

Comment: @hsfzxjy Yes, done, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It seems that vs hasnt update the pyc binary file..

Comment: For python I prefer sublime text and bash to be the developing environment. I don't know how vs     work with python but it will be terribly awful if it won't recompile the file per running.